# Heroku Postgres performance monitoring with pg_stat_statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I've been trying to troubleshoot some recurring H12/13 errors on Heroku.  After exhausting everything I can find on Google/Heroku/Stack Overflow I'm now checking to see if some long-running database queries are causing the problem on the advice of Heroku support.

Update: I'm on a production Crane instance. Per the accepted answer below...it appears you cannot do this on Heroku.  The best I've been able to do is filter them out per the SQL below:

```
SELECT u.usename, (total_time / 1000 / 60) as total_minutes, 
       (total_time/calls) as average_time, query 
FROM pg_stat_statements p 
JOIN pg_user u ON (u.usesysid = p.userid) 
WHERE query != '<insufficient privilege>'
ORDER BY 2 
DESC LIMIT 10;
```

---

I'm trying to use Craig Kerstien's very useful post, 
http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/01/10/more-on-postgres-performance/ but running into some permission issues.

When I query the pg_stat_statements table I get "insufficient privileges" for some of the longer-running queries and it doesn't appear that Heroku lets you change user permissions.

Does anyone know how I can change permissions see these queries on Heroku?

```
heroku pg:psql --remote production
psql (9.2.2, server 9.2.4)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

d4k2qvm4tmu579=> SELECT 
d4k2qvm4tmu579->   (total_time / 1000 / 60) as total_minutes, 
d4k2qvm4tmu579->   (total_time/calls) as average_time, 
d4k2qvm4tmu579->   query 
d4k2qvm4tmu579-> FROM pg_stat_statements 
d4k2qvm4tmu579-> ORDER BY 1 DESC 
d4k2qvm4tmu579-> LIMIT 10;
  total_minutes   |   average_time    |          query           
------------------+-------------------+--------------------------
 121.755079699998 |  11.7572250919775 | <insufficient privilege>
 17.9371053166656 |  1.73208859315089 | <insufficient privilege>
 13.8710526000023 |  1.33945202190106 | <insufficient privilege>
 6.98494270000089 | 0.674497883626922 | <insufficient privilege>
 6.75377774999972 | 0.652175543095124 | <insufficient privilege>
 6.55192439999995 | 0.632683664174224 | <insufficient privilege>
 3.84014626666634 |  1.12786802880252 | <insufficient privilege>
 3.40574066666667 |  1399.61945205479 | <insufficient privilege>
 3.16332020000008 | 0.929081204384053 | <insufficient privilege>
 2.30192519999944 | 0.222284382614463 | <insufficient privilege>
(10 rows)
```

Comment: You are not able to query the db as a database superuser? (eg. "postgres")

Comment: As far as I can tell from Heroku's documentation you cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be running a production level instance of Heroku Postgres in order to utilize  pg_stat_statements. Even then, it will only be able to show you stats for queries run by your app (or any client using the heroku supplied credentials). You won't be able to see queries for superusers (posters, collectd). Production plans are Crane and up (I believe).

You can see the username by joining in pg_user:

```
SELECT u.usename, (total_time / 1000 / 60) as total_minutes, 
       (total_time/calls) as average_time, query 
FROM pg_stat_statements p 
JOIN pg_user u ON (u.usesysid = p.userid) ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your question directly but maybe take a look at the pg-extra's plugin which brings a lot of this goodness directly to the Heroku CLI and returns data :)

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras

Comment: Thank you, this looks really useful, this problem notwithstanding.